# How to find loss values using keras?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I want to use the various loss function defined in keras for calculating the loss value manually. For example:

```
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
error=binary_crossentropy([1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9])
```

gives me error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'.
```

Similar way I want to use other keras loss function. I have my y_pred and y_true lists/arrays.

Comment: use numpy arrays instead of lists

Comment: Done that, converted my list to numpy array but I get this `AttributeError: 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'`.

​

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `K.variable()` to wrap the inputs and use `K.eval()` to get the value.

```
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
from keras import backend as K
y_true = K.variable(np.array([[1], [0], [1], [1]]))
y_pred = K.variable(np.array([[0.5], [0.6], [0.7], [0.8]]))
error = K.eval(binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred))

print(error)
[ 0.69314718  0.91629082  0.35667494  0.22314353]
```