# Calculate the model compiled loss and metrics from predicted scores

Tags: tensorflow, keras

After training the model, I use the [`predict`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) method to infer the scores from my testing data.

From the predicted scores how can I use the model compiled loss and metrics to calculate the loss of my predictions?

### What I have tried

Based on [Customizing what happens in `fit()`](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/) guide I tried using the `compiled_loss` method

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
model.compiled_loss(y_test, y_pred, regularization_losses=model.losses)
```

But it returns the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-6-3eb62dca0b87> in <module>()
      1 y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
----> 2 loss = model.compiled_loss(y_test, y_pred)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py in match_dtype_and_rank(y_t, y_p, sw)
    673 def match_dtype_and_rank(y_t, y_p, sw):
    674   """Match dtype and rank of predictions."""
--> 675   if y_t.shape.rank == 1 and y_p.shape.rank == 2:
    676     y_t = tf.expand_dims(y_t, axis=-1)
    677   if sw is not None:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank'
```

### How to reproduce

I used the [Simple MNIST convnet](https://keras.io/examples/vision/mnist_convnet/) example followed by

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
model.compiled_loss(y_test, y_pred, regularization_losses=model.losses)
```

to reproduce the error

### About my problem

I am validating my data on a custom metric. However some Keras users recommended that global metrics should not be averaged by batch, instead, calculated from the predicted scores for the whole validation data in a Callback.

See:

[Issue #5794](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5794)

[How to calculate F1 Macro in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547402/how-to-calculate-f1-macro-in-keras)

The bad solution to this is to calculate the loss and metrics from the [`evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate) method, and my custom metric from `predict`. The problem with this is that I am running the inference twice.

A less worse solution is to implement my loss function separately so it can work from the predicted scores.

See:

[Calculate loss in Keras without running the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57975763/calculate-loss-in-keras-without-running-the-model/57976403#57976403)

The issue with this is that it gives me less flexibility to choose loss functions because I have to implement every loss function separately in the Callback later.

But I really wonder, isn't the compiled loss and metrics accessible somewhere already?

Comment: The solution might be `evaluate` but you said it's a bad solution. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @M.Innat it is bad in a sense that evaluate and predict both runs inference in my test set, doubling the time taken for validation after each epoch, which will be an issue for large datasets. See https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11705#issuecomment-443451661 . My question is exactly that though: “How can I calculate the loss and the scores in a single dataset pass?” or “Can I calculate the loss from the predicted scores?” As far as I know, model.evaluate will return the loss and metrics I compiled with the model, so I can not calculate any custom global metric later.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that can calculate the metrics given the previously predicted output:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def calculate_metrics(model, y, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y)
    y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
    if not sample_weight is None:
        sample_weight = tf.convert_to_tensor(sample_weight)
    model.compute_loss(x=None, y=y, y_pred=y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight)
    metrics = model.compute_metrics(x=None, y=y, y_pred=y_pred,
                                    sample_weight=sample_weight)
    for k,v in metrics.items():
        metrics[k] = float(v)
    return metrics
```

It expects `y`, `y_pred`, and `sample_weight` (if provided) to be numpy arrays.  This means that they need to fit in memory at once.  It also means that the metric values could be slightly different than what is returned by [`model.evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate), but I think you understand that, given your comment that "global metrics should not be averaged by batch."

---

> But it returns the error
>
> `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank'`

`model.compiled_loss` (as well as `model.compute_loss` and `model.compute_metrics`) expects the inputs to each be a [`Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor). Tensors have an attribute `shape`, which is of type [`TensorShape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape), which in turn has an attribute `rank`. I expect that your `y_test` was an [`ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), which also has an attribute `shape`, but that is of type `tuple`, which does not have an attribute `rank`.  This is why my function converts the inputs to Tensors.  The metric values returned are also Tensors, so I manually convert each of those to an ordinary python `float`.

---

> But I really wonder, isn't the compiled loss and metrics accessible somewhere already?

The metrics are available in the [`History`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/History) object returned by the [`model.fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) method, so if you're evaluating a newly trained model, you don't need to recalculate the metrics.  However, if you're loading a previously trained model and want to get the metrics, you need to either use [`model.evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate) or calculate the metrics from the result of [`model.predict`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) as we do here.  Taking a look at the code, you can compare [`model.test_step`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.10.0/keras/engine/training.py#L1640-L1668) and [`model.predict_step`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.10.0/keras/engine/training.py#L1962-L1983), respectively.  Note that `model.predict_step` just runs the inference and returns the prediction, so the metrics are never calculated when you run `model.predict`.  A better solution than the one I provide would be to combine elements of `model.predict` into `model.evaluate` so that it can optionally return the `y_pred` instead of discarding it after the metrics are calculated, but that would require modifying tensorflow code.